# How to change checkbox label dynamically in Gravity form

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, multipage

I have created a multi page form using gravity form WordPress plugin. I have created a check box and need to show different label when checked and unchecked the checkbox.
I have done that using JQuery for single page form,
but in multi page forms It dose not work.
Is there any proper way to do that

Comment: you just have to create helper js file in that you can write js. and when you need it just call that js function

Comment: finad a solution https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_post_render/
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi page Gravity form load other page without reloading whole web page,
So if write jQuery that may not identify the hidden part of the form.
So we can use

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function() {});
```

to fire our jQuery function after form pages load.

Ref: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_post_render/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){

        // destroy default Gravity Form datepicker
        jQuery("#your_id").datepicker('destroy');

        // create new custom datepicker
        jQuery("#your_id").datepicker({ defaultDate: '+7d', minDate: '+7d', gotoCurrent: true, prevText: *, showOn: 'both', buttonImage: '/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/calendar.png', buttonImageOnly: true });

    });

</script>
```